# How to deploy a plugin to Jenkins Hosting?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to create a new release from my plugin and I just can't make it work.

The general document I try to follow is this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hosting+Plugins

I managed to get just about every possible error message on that page (connection refused, publickey, 401 unauthorized) and tried many combination of the suggestion there and here and across the web, but no luck so far.

I have a user in JenkinsCI, also in GitHub and permission in the infra.

Can you point me to a list of steps that cause a successful deployment? Please be as specific as possible.

- where to run? cmd? GitHub-Desktop Shell (cmd? bash? PowerShell?) regular Git-Bash? (each gives me different result)
- pom.xml setting? which parent to use? I tried all including the latest 2.14, again, with each version giving me different error

What should I do to test it before I run? I've run mvn release:perpare release:perform and it caused my version number to increase many times for no reason. should 'mvn deploy' also work? (it doesn't)

Comment: You should be able to run your command line from a cmd/terminal and activate the -X option that would bring more information about the actions taken, in particular URL targeted, authentication used and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it to work (it was very hard, endless tries).

The bottom line was nothing exciting, most of the clues were in the original document https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hosting+Plugins (Which I read 2,000 times, each time noticing another nuance that was important). The original plugin was released 3 years ago, things have changed since that caused most of the problems.

This is the set-up that eventually worked:

- GitHub Desktop installation
- I used the shell that comes with it (the default, PowerShell one)
- Needed to set up SSH keys for it
- I needed to fill the PR for permission (this is new, it was not needed back then)
- My Jenkins CI account no longer worked apparently - I needed to reset the password
- I got 'Unauthorized' errors, so I upgrade my parent pom to 2.10 (like suggested here https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/jenkinsci-dev/PFD_b370H20/nh2EX99SCAAJ
- Updating the parent gave lots of other issues, I tried all the combinations 2.14-2.6, eventually settled for 2.10 and fixed the compilation issue (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jelly+and+XSS+prevention)
- Upgrading the parent did NOT solve the authorization so I also followed the workaround here - https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/commit/c9f6cbae246e038d7cb2cd97ecf72efc0212971a